# subset in R based on factor level n-times given a vector of matching variables

Tags: r

Newbie in R and I've been trying to find a neat (not using a loop) way to do the following:

```
x <- c(0, 4)
y <- c(1, 2)
df <- data.frame(x,y)
```

therefore if I want to output all x for which y=1:

```
df$x[df$y == 1]
```

but what if I have a vector such as a <- c(1,1,1)?

I can't just do:

```
df$x[df$y == a]
```

because it subsets just once:

[1] 0

but I want the output to be the vector c(0,0,0)

Obviously this isn't the way to go about it, but any clues as to which is?

Thanks!

Comment: Title of your question doesn't tell what you want to do... Try to change it to proper context... Otherwise your question is already answered.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is `%in%`. Try:

```
df$x[df$y %in% a]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `%in%`:

```
df$x[df$y %in% a]
```

`%in%` returns TRUE for each value in `df$y` when it is *in* `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to do this is

```
df[df$y %in% a,]$x
```

or

```
df[df$y %in% a,'x']
```

Comment: I edited your question because there were two different data.frames in your answer, `df` and `sd`, which were probably just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, the desired result is the vector `c(0,0,0)`. One way you could achieve that is:

```
rep(df$x[df$y %in% a], length(a))
#[1] 0 0 0
```

But you need to be aware of the implications, for example if you change `a` so that it contains different numbers. Here's another example:

```
a <- c(3,1,2)
rep(df$x[df$y %in% a], length(a))
#[1] 0 4 0 4 0 4
```

So in this case, the output has a length of `2*length(a)` because two different values of `a` match an entry in `df$y`. It is not clear from your question what behavior you want in such a case. So here's a third example if you want each value of `a` repeated only as often as the number of elements in `a` that are also present in `df$y`:

```
a <- c(3,1,2)
rep(df$x[df$y %in% a], length(a[a %in% df$y]))
#[1] 0 4 0 4
```